# check that values in lists match

Tags: c#, list

I have 2 lists as described below

How can i verify that all **sitempath** values that exist in **lstOldItems** also exist in **lstNewItems**

**C# Code**

```
List<ItemsUnderControlObject> lstNewItems
List<ItemsUnderControlObject> lstOldItems


public class ItemsUnderControlObject
{
 public ItemsUnderControlObject();

 public bool bButtonEnabled { get; set; }
 public short iChkInterval { get; set; }
 public int iItemUnderCtrlUniqueID { get; set; }
 public DateTime? ItemCreationDateTime { get; set; }
 public DateTime? ItemLastAccessDateTime { get; set; }
 public DateTime? ItemLastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
 public long lngItemSize { get; set; }
 public string sItemBackupLocation { get; set; }
 public string sItemcategory { get; set; }
 public string sItemCurrentStatus { get; set; }
 public DateTime sItemDatabaseCreationDateTime { get; set; }
 public string sItemName { get; set; }
 public string sItemPath { get; set; }
 public string sItemRequestStatus { get; set; }
 public string sItemTask { get; set; }
 public string sItemValue { get; set; }
 public string sItemValueSHA256 { get; set; }
 public string sSystemID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i tried this but count isnt good enough - i need to check that they are the EXACT same.                List<ItemsUnderControlObject> results = lstNewItems.FindAll(x => x.sitempath != "Add"); // If other changes have been made since these changes then abort
                if (results.Count != MyGlobals.ListOlditems.Count)

Comment: Are you looking for reference equality (i.e., they are the same object) or a custom equality (e.g., all of the properties are equal)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner, in case you don't want to extract the paths to different lists:

```
stOldItems.All(x => lstNewItems.Any(y=> x.sItemPath == y.sItemPath));
```

Comment: @IronMan84 Why was `==` changed to `.Equals`? When we know the property is of type `string`, it's natural to use `==`. And the problem with the `Equals` instance method is that if some `string` is `null`, it can throw an exception.

Comment: `String.Equals` should do the trick. `"It is best to avoid using the == and != operators when you compare strings"`. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165449.aspx

Comment: "Compare strings" can mean two things: (1) Check for equality. (2) Find out if the first one is greater than or less than the other one. The default for (1) is to do an ordinal comparison. The default for (2) is to do culture-dependent and case-sensitive comparison. There are many equivalent syntaxes for both kinds of comparisons. When the ***compile-time*** types of both operands are `string`, and when an ordinal comparison for equality is wanted, I would **always** use the `==` operator. To me it seems crazy to write `String.Equals(a, b)` when it is equivalent to `a == b`.

Comment: Yes, `a == b` uses the operator overload from `string` that does `Equals(a, b)`. I don't know why they say it should be avoided tho.

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders Maybe they want you to write `String.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.Ordinal)` to make it absolutely explicit that you want ordinal and case-sensitive comparison. But I don't agree with their advice, and I would do `a == b` as I said.

Comment: @ Jeppe Stig Nielsen, Agreed, i don't see the point of avoiding the `==` operator in this case, i've rolled it back.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use LINQ's `Except` extension method [seen here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

```
var oldItemPaths = lstOldItems.Select(l => l.sItemPath).Distinct();
var newItemPaths = lstNewItems.Select(l => l.sItemPath).Distinct();
bool isSame = !oldItemPaths.Except(newItemPaths).Any();
```

Or, using @Magnus' way of doing it with the above code (minus the `Except`):

```
bool isSame = oldItemPaths.All(x => newItemPaths.Contains(x));
```

Comment: The `Distinct` is not necessary since `Except` removes the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

For fast look-up first add the items in `lstNewItems` to a `HashSet`, than use [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx):

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(lstNewItems.Select(x => x.sItemPath));
var res = lstOldItems.All(x => set.Contains(x.sItemPath));
```

Comment: Or with `set` as above, `var res = set.IsSupersetOf(lstOldItems.Select(x => x.sItemPath));`.

Comment: This answer clearly performs better than the other ones when the lists are long.

Answer (score 1):

try linq,

something along the lines of this

```
List<string> sitempaths = lstNewItems.Select(i => i.sitempath).ToList();

bool hasSitempaths = lstOldItems
    .Where(x => sitempaths.contains(x.sitempath)).ToList()
    .Count == lstOldItems.Count;
```

note, this is not actually tested, you might have to adjsut